# Connection Timeout Error while connecting to mongoDB with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am new to Node.js trying to connect node with Mongo
but getting an Error in console

> ongooseTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
>       at new MongooseTimeoutError (/home/waqar/Documents/ToDoApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/timeout.js:22:11)
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/waqar/Documents/ToDoApp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:763

Here is My Code

```
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');


  //connect to Database
  try {
    // i have changed connection string just for security purpose
    mongoose.connect(
      'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"',
      {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
      }
    );
    console.log('Connected');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Caught', err);
  }
  // schema for toDo app
  var toDoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    item: String
  });


  // Create TOdo Model
  var Todo  = mongoose.model('Todo',toDoSchema);


  var urlEncodeParser=bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

module.exports = function (app) {

  app.get('/todo',function(req,res){
    // Get Data From Mongooese and pass it to vi
    Todo.find({},function(err,data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.render('todo',{todos:data});
    });
  });

  app.post('/todo',urlEncodeParser,function(req,res){
    // Get ata from the view and post it  to Mongooese DB
    var newTodo = Todo(req.body).save(function(err,data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(data);
    });
  });

  app.delete('/todo/:item',function(req,res){
    // Delete the requested Item from Mongoo DB
    Todo.find(req.item.params.replace(/\-/g," ")).remove(function(err,data) {
      res.json(data);
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: You have provided almost zero details on your database.  I assume you are trying to connect to Atlas since you are using a URI with SRV record references.  Two points -  If this is Atlas, ensure you enabled the whitelist ACL to allow your client to communicate, and second point - try to connect with a known working tool like mongoshell before trying to debug your program (verify connectivity).

Comment: can you please give me reference on both points any answered question

Comment: Atlas whitelist is a firewall concept for security.  Which computers by ip address are allowed to communicate with the Atlas database.  See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: mongo shell is a command line database tool included with the community edition of MongoDB.  It installs on a client computer.  It could be installed on your nodejs development computer.  It provides a way to connect to Atlas to prove connectivity and whitelist access control lists (ACL)s.  See usage of mongo shell with Atlas at https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/mongo-shell-connection/